# How to add dependencies in BUCK

Tags: java, buck

When I import libraries such as "org.json", I get an error. I know to add the dependencies in POM file if it's a maven project, but it's compiled using BUCK, so how do I add this dependency and it's version in BUCK?

Comment: Can you show any code that you have or setup needed?

Comment: Take a look at this project setup here https://github.com/LoopPerfect/buckaroo/blob/master/BUCK deps are downloaded from Maven

Comment: Thanks, eventually I found out the same. BUCK uses maven build initially to get the jar files from the internet. So I had to do a manual mvn install to get the jar file. Then BUCK build worked after including the dependency in the BUCK and deps file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the the build rules section of buck docs - https://buck.build/concept/build_rule.html

For java libraries we would care about java_library - https://buck.build/rule/java_library.html

e.g

If we wanted to add the uber cadence library(https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-client) to our project we would add
"//3rdparty/jvm/com/uber/cadence:cadence-client-2.7.8.jar" to the deps section of our BUCK file and then run ./buckw project [project-name] to compile or use the buck ide plugin to run ./buckw project within the ide

add to BUCK file

```
java_library(
  ...
  deps = [
    ...
    "//third_party/cadence:cadence-client-2.7.8.jar",
  ],
)
```